# Excel - Overlapping Data - Pivottable

Tags: excel-formula, pivot-table, powerpivot

Is it possible to create a table for data with overlapping values within the same column?
I would prefer a pivot table where I could slice the data instead of Venn Diagram.

[image: Output Picture]

Data

```
 1. Red / Material 1
 2. Red / Material 2
 3. Red / Material 3
 4. Red / Material 4
 5. Red / Material 5
 6. Blue / Material 1
 7. Blue / Material 6
 8. Blue / Material 7
 9. Blue / Material 8
 10. Blue / Material 9
 11. Blue / Material 10
 12. Blue / Material 11
 13. Blue / Material 12
 14. Green / Material 1
 15. Green / Material 2
 16. Green / Material 6
 17. Green / Material 7
 18. Green / Material 8
 19. Green / Material 13
 20. Green / Material 14
```

Comment: How is "yellow" calculated in your example?

Comment: sorry, pls discard the "Yellow" criteria.

Comment: okay, so what is the relation between `material` and the color? Do the material numbers (1-14) match with the (1-20) numbers in the first columns?

Comment: The relationship would be the frequency of 2 colors for each material# appear together.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put all the real details into it, so people don't have to stitch it together from your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a table that has combinations of colors like this:

```
Color  Color2
-------------
Red    Red
Red    Blue
Red    Green
Blue   Red
Blue   Blue
Blue   Green
Green  Red
Green  Blue
Green  Green
```

One way to do this is to created a calculated `Colors` table like this:

```
Colors = CROSSJOIN(SELECTCOLUMNS(VALUES(Data[Color]), "Color", Data[Color]),
                   SELECTCOLUMNS(VALUES(Data[Color]), "Color2", Data[Color]))
```

Now we can create a calculated column on this table that counts the intersecting values:

```
Count = 
    VAR Materials1 = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Data[Material]),
                         Data[Color] = EARLIER(Colors[Color]))
    VAR Materials2 = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Data[Material]),
                         Data[Color] = EARLIER(Colors[Color2]))
    RETURN IF(Colors[Color] = Colors[Color2], BLANK(),
               COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(Materials1, Materials2)))
```

Now you can set them up in a matrix visual with `Color` on the Rows and `Color2` on the Columns and `Count` in the Values box.

[image: Matrix]